# Set debug point in visual code and have it paused on Chrome Devtools debugger

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, google-chrome-devtools

I want to be able to set a debug point directly in visual code but have the code stop in chrome debugger so that I can debug it there.

I'm not looking to debug in the visual code app but rather only set the debug point there.

Also not looking to alter the code by putting `debugger` in the code.

Using Angular 13.

Comment: I think this is a feature included the Chrome Debugger extension

Comment: @anut thanks for comment. Chrome debugger extension has been depreciated in favour of built in vs-code debugger. And I couldn't find any options for this in there